window.getComputedStyle() doesn't work within MutationObserver
I'm using window.getComputedStyle when node added into document.body. But there's a problem: it's always outputs none, but I'm sure that child have a filter style and it's not none. What's the problem?
My code is:
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationList, observer) => {
    for (const mutation of mutationList) {
        const target = mutation.target;
        const style = window.getComputedStyle(target);
        console.log(style.filter);
    }
});

observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });

I tried to use setTimeout and others but it didn't solve the problem

mutationList will contain a reference to the element which was mutated, ie. document.body, not the child element.

additional to what Rory said, try to select the element by Class Name or Id Name, or descendant selector,  window.getComputedStyle(target) doesn't make sense for me

@medou-boushab, I actually tried it and I dont know why, but it doesn't fixed the problem. But anyways, thanks to you and to Rory McCrossan

The issue is because mutationList will contain a reference to the element which was mutated, ie. document.body, not the child element. Clearly, the body doesn't have the filter applied to it.
To fix the issue you need to interrogate the mutated element within the handler to find the new content, which is accessible via the addedNodes property, and check the filter value there.


const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationList, observer) => {
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {    
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach(child => {        
      const style = window.getComputedStyle(child);
      console.log(style.filter);      
    });
  }
});

const container = document.querySelector('#container');
observer.observe(container, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});

// for demo only
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = 'foo';
  span.style = 'filter: blur(1px)';
  container.appendChild(span);
});
span {
  display: block;
}
<button>Add element</button>

<div id="container"></div>




It didn't work for me when i tried to observe a whole page using document.body

Odd - it still works absolutely fine on document.body: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4xwfzhjm/. I forgot to mention I changed to the div container in the example because SO snippets dump a bunch of additional content (the console for one) which broke the outcome.

I don't know. It doesn't work at twitter. I'm codding an extension for Twitter
